# Parsing JSON response using groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I am new to groovy and need to parse JSON response. the response looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "start_date": "2016-09-30",
        "sort_order": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Tony",
        "start_date": "2016-06-30",
        "sort_order": 2
    }
]
```

How can I get each object from that? would like to end up with name, start_date and sort_order for each student together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `JsonSlurper`

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = '''[ 
    { "name": "John", "start_date": "2016-09-30", "sort_order": 1 },
    { "name": "Tony", "start_date": "2016-06-30", "sort_order": 2 } ]'''

def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

assert parsed.name == ['John', 'Tony']
```

Comment: To get what you're asking for Punter do this, but it would be parsed.each { println it }  that should get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I should have been a little more clearer on what outcome i want, which is to print total object count and then to have print each object. i.e. total students= 2, student 1 is (name = john, start_date = 2016-09-30), student 2 is (name = Tony, start_date = 2016-06-30) according to the sort order

Comment: Added this bit to get what i want. Thanks tim_yates and dataman. for (item in parsed){
 def name = item.name
 def startDate = item.start_date
 def sortOrder = item.sort_order

 println "name is : " + name
 println "startDate is : " + startDate
 println "sortOrder is : " + sortOrder
}